# What is the probability of answering a question correctly when we are 100% sure some of the answers are correct?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Scenario :

In a Mathematics test, each student must answer 20 true or false questions. A student that is sitting for the test knows the correct answer for 8 questions but he tosses a coin to determine the answers for the remaining questions.

Question :

Find the probability that he can answer at least 90% of the questions correctly.

Answer provided in the book :

[image]

My way to answer :

(Since 8 questions are 100% correct, so I just do not count them in)

[image]

Which method is correct?

If the method 1 is correct, we have already known 8 questions are 100% correct, how can *p* be 0.7?

Shouldn't we exclude those 8 questions when counting the probability?

Comment: You are correct. The question is not clear and the solution probably assumes that it could be any $8$ questions that the student knows answers to.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. 
I found this has the similar question with mine
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608501/probability-of-answering-correctly-a-question
so if my solution is correct, in what situation will the solution 1 be applied to find the "p" ?

Comment: Well... you could find $p$ as $0.7$ as above for the probability of getting a particular question that was randomly chosen correct.  The error of the book's approach is not in finding $p$... but rather in assuming that the binomial distribution applies.  Recall that in the binomial distribution, it is implied then that there is positive probability of having zero or one or two successes, etc... but that is clearly not the case here for this problem since we are always guaranteed a minimum of eight correct answers.  It follows then that the outcomes of each question are *dependent* on eachother

Comment: That a book could make such a blatant mistake is disheartening.  That is an incredibly rookie mistake that only students first starting should make.  It is good to see that you caught it and are aware enough and understand the material enough to realize that it was wrong.

Comment: This is not the first time this book make such mistake, it sometimes confuses me with the wrong approach in the idea of solving. 
Thank you, I finally get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for showing your work: In R, where `dbinom` is a binomial PDF: code `sum(dbinom(10:12,12,.5))` returns $ 0.01928711,$ essentially your answer.